# How the probabilities are calculated: Shannon's noiseless coding theorem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

This question refers to the section 13.1.2 of the book:

Quantum Information, Computation and Communication by JONATHAN A. JONES AND DIETER JAKSCH

The text goes as following:

"
We choose to encode AA as 0, AB as 10, and B as 11. No extra “start/stop” bits indicating the beginning or ending of a message are necessary since it is understood that bit strings starting with 1 have a length of two bits while a 0 indicates a bit string of length one bit. The message string AA occurs with probability pAA = p2, AB with pAB = p(1− p), and B with pB = 1− p.
If the number of substrings to be encoded is Ns, then the number of bits in the encoded
string will on average be Ne = pAA Ns + 2pAB Ns + 2pB Ns and these Ns encodings will on
average have encoded No = 2pAA Ns + 2pAB Ns + pB Ns messages.
"

It might be a lame question but can anyone please explain how the terms Ne and No are calculated? How do we decide the coefficient '2' used here?

Any reference in addition would also be helpful.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

> It might be a lame question but can anyone please explain how the terms Ne and No are calculated?

$N_e$ is the average number of bits in the encoded string.

So it is equal to the average number of AA symbols times the length of the encoding for AA, plus the average number of AB symbols times the length of the encoding for AB, plus the average number of B symbols times the length of the encoding for B.

The average number of AA symbols is the probability of an AA symbol occurring times the total number of symbols. The average number of AB and B symbols are calculated similarly.

> How do we decide the coefficient '2' used here?

2 is the length of the encoding for an AB or B symbol.